# AWS IoT STM32L4 Stuck on Write Certificates

Tags: aws-iot

I am new to AWS IoT and working with STM32L475 Discovery kit board and trying to run the AWS freeRTOS demo for the board based on the [AWS getting started guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/getting_started_st.html). I followed all the steps provided in the AWS documentation but encountering the following error.

[Console output seems to be stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTPBZ.png)

I had checked the AWS credentials and they are correct. I used the quick connect method to register my board and create the Iot Thing. I erased the flash memory before debugging the project thinking that might be causing the issue.
I also upgraded the board to latest Firmware and also updated the Wifi firmware (making sure I am using the .STM.bin file).

I am using System workbench on windows 10 (64 bit) for the project and Teraterm serial terminal with speed setting 115200
I see nothing on AWS Iot Console.

Could anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue? Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I realized that the x509 certificates on my dev board were not working. Ersing the MCU and repeating the process solved the issue.